# How to query between two MSSQL databases with the same schema and combine results in Entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework

I have a database that currently holds all the transactions data. It is growing **exponentially** in size because of the growth of the business. [More business, More Transactions, More space needed for the database]. Because of the **large sums of data**, my database queries have been ***slowed down***. So I have planned to have another database to store the legacy [Historical] data.

However, when I am picking specific transaction details or number of transactions, I want it in such a way that if the transaction(s) is not found in the transactions database, I want **Entity framework** to automatically look it up in the **Legacy information**.  The transactions database has information for a specified period of time. So if the time [in the select query] is past the specified period, I want Entity framework to query the legacy information database and not the transactions database.

If the query has results from both databases, I want Entity framework to be able to combine the results and give me one result set. I would not want to start **sending individual queries to the various databases** and start combining the results manually! Is there a way Entity framework can do this for me automatically?

Both the transactions and legacy information databases have the same schema.

How do I achieve the above objective? Thank you

Comment: I don't think entity has a *federation* functionality to demultiplex queries for different sources. You will have to code this yourself. This would start to get ugly when schemas start to differ, or have outdated versions.

Comment: SQL Server supports [Partitioned View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#partitioned-views)s and [Partitioned Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/partitioned-tables-and-indexes?view=sql-server-2017)s functionalities just for this type of problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can make result in Store procedure or view and added this objects to Entity Framework.
**Entity Framework is an Object Relational Mapper(ORM) which is a type of tool that simplifies mapping between objects in your software to the tables and columns of a relational database**
You must support this capability in your **query result** that can run as **job** in specific times .